# JavaScript regex matching an attribute in tag if another specific attribute is present

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string pattern:

```
<div content="[...]" class="[...]">[...]</div>
<div content="website" [...] class="_type">[...]</div>
<dic content="[...]" class="[...]">[...]</div>
```

My question is how I can get the "website" text using code here.

I have tried:

```
/content="(.+?)".*?class="_type"/g
```

But the result is not expected: `[...]`.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regexes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1835379).

Comment: Cannot agree more with @Cerbrus. JQuery / JavaScript is your friend.

Comment: You should avoid regular expressions for HTML. You could probably use `.getAttribute("content")`.

Comment: @npinti `getAttribute` isn't going to work if it's a string. ;)

Comment: Oh no, this is textstring i want regex in meanio, but jquery and html

Comment: @JamesDonnelly: I'm not a JS guy, but doing this: `document.getElementsByClassName("_type")[0].getAttribute("content");` yielded `website`.

Comment: @npinti the question states "I have a string paterm". Sounds like OP has a string containing those 3 `div` elements, but they don't actually exist on the page `"<div content="...">...</div><div ...>..."`.

Comment: thanks sir for reply, but i want use regex javascript for this. You have any idea.

Comment: @James Donnelly: Thanks sir, But my languge english is bad, i want say more more... but i can't... i just have example and code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a regex that can get that substring.

```
var re = /<(?=[^<>]*\bclass="_type")div\b[^<>]*content="([^"]*)"/ig;
```

The regex is matching any `<div>` containing string that has `content="` and also containing `class="_type"`. The result is stored in the captured group 1. Note that `class="_type"` can be both before or after `content="{our string}"`.

The code can be something like:

```js
var re = /<(?=[^<>]*\bclass="_type")div\b[^<>]*content="([^"]*)"/ig; 
var str = '<div content="[...]" class="[...]">[...]</div>\n<div content="website" [...] class="_type">[...]</div>\n<dic content="[...]" class="[...]">[...]</div>';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

In case you do not know what kind of delimiters there will be in HTML, it makes it a bit more problematic. However, it is still possible:

```js
var re = /<(?=[^<>]*\bclass=['"]?_type\b['"]?)div\b[^<>]*content=(?:["']([^<]*?)["']|(\S+))/ig; 
var str = '<div content="[...]" class="[...]">[...]</div>\n<div content=\'[...]\' class=\'[...]\'>[...]</div>\n<div content="web site" [...] class="_type">[...]</div>\n<dic content="[...]" class="[...]">[...]</div>\n<dic content=[...] class=[...]>[...]</div>\n<dic content=\'[...]\' class=\'[...]\'>[...]</div>\n<div content=\'web site\' [...] class=\'_type\'>[...]</div>\n<div content=website [...] class=_type>[...]</div>';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    if (m[1] === undefined) {
      document.getElementById("e").innerHTML += m[2] + "<br/>";
    }
  else {
      document.getElementById("e").innerHTML += m[1] + "<br/>";
    }
    
}
```

```html
<div id="e"/>
```

Comment: So, what if the target `div` also has another class on it? Like `class="_type someClass"`?

Comment: @Cerbrus: It won't match it. The lookahead checks for the existence of `class="_type"` exactly.

Comment: Which is exactly what I meant. This is why one doesn't process HTML with regexes. There's always something that'll break the regex.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I do not understand what you mean at all. The requirement is so clear and simple that even a regex is safe to use  here. We only match the "content" if there is `class="_type"`.

Comment: Assuming no other classes are ever found in the `_type` elements

Comment: All i want say now is thanks @stribizhev, code runing good althought class="_type" before or after content="website".. Very good, and althought i see code i not undestand :)

Comment: I will explain in a little while, sorry, too busy right now.

Comment: @stribizhev i want to say 1 sub question is if  `str = <div content='website' [...] class='_type'` solution for " -> ' and ' -> "

Comment: I added a solution to all possible cases.